# Splitting a dictionary like object into new columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have this dataframe. How I got this dataframe was due to using `.to_dict()`. It manages to split the initial dictionary into individual columns on key:value pairs. However some keys has a dictionary like value. For instance like the **Ambience** column here.

I believe the initial dictionary is something like this

```
attribute = {
    "AcceptsInsurance": "null",
    "AgesAllowed": "null',
    "Ambience": {
        'touristy': False,
        'hipster': False,
        'romantic': False,
        'divey': False,
        'intimate': False
      }
    } ...
```

To be exact, [image]

The column value are in a dictionary like object but are not dictionary. The column are in object type.

```
+---------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+                  
|    business_id|                                                                                    Ambience|  
+---------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|6iYb2HFDywm3zjw|{'touristy': False, 'hipster': False, 'romantic': False, 'divey': False, 'intimate': False} | 
|drRPZA0oiIYSmqs|{'romantic': False, 'intimate': False, 'classy': False, False, 'casual': True}              |  
+---------------+-------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I would like to hence further split it and create new column for each of the element of the key:value pair. So something like this,

```
+-----------------+------------------+-------------------+
|      business_id| Ambience_touristy|  Ambience_romantic|
+-----------------+------------------+-------------------+
|  6iYb2HFDywm3zjw|             False|              False|
|  drRPZA0oiIYSmqs|              Null|              False|
+-----------------+------------------+-------------------+
```

How do I go about doing this? I am new to this and would appreciate any help.

Comment: could you share the dictionary that constructs the dataframe you have here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

re-using a function from another SO answer called `unnesting()` with modifications. edit: please note that the string in row 2 is not a valid Python dictionary. this solution assumes valid Python dictionaries.

```
def unnesting(df, explode):
    """ modified from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53218939/42346 """
    df1 = pd.concat( 
        [ 
            pd.DataFrame(df[x].tolist(), index=df.index).add_prefix(x + "_") 
            if x == "Ambience" 
            else pd.DataFrame(df[x], index=df.index) 
            for x in explode 
        ], 
        axis=1, 
    ) 
    return df1.join(df.drop(explode, 1), how="left")
```

you can then do:

```
import ast

df["Ambience"] = df["Ambience"].apply(ast.literal_eval) 
df_unnested = unnesting(df, ["business_id", "Ambience"])
```

result:

```
       business_id Ambience_touristy Ambience_hipster  Ambience_romantic  Ambience_divey  Ambience_intimate Ambience_classy Ambience_casual
1  6iYb2HFDywm3zjw             False            False              False           False              False             NaN             NaN
2  drRPZA0oiIYSmqs               NaN              NaN              False           False              False           False            True
```

Comment: thank you for replying. I am however receiving an 'malformed node or string: None' error

Comment: @reign: that occurs because the example dictionary in the 2nd row is not a valid Python dictionary. be sure all of your dictionaries are valid Python dictionaries.